# Refresh token for IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

We are implementing IdentityServer4 and trying to figure out why we are not getting a refresh token.  Using the created examples I am trying to make sure I get refresh token at least on my local machine.  So far no luck.

The client is configured like so:

```cs
new Client
{
    ClientId = "client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 60
},
```

The test program that's using the client looks like this:

```cs
/* CLIENT AUTHENTICATION WITH A KNOWN SECRET */
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1");

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TOKEN ERROR:\r\n" + tokenResponse.Error);
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

    var numberOfSeconds = 10;

    while( numberOfSeconds < 600 ) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"slept for for {numberOfSeconds}");
        Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
    
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:52801/api/identity");
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("API ERROR:\r\n" + response.StatusCode);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("API RESPONSE:\r\n" + JArray.Parse(content));
        }

        numberOfSeconds += 10;
    }
}
```

The token when printed out looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjRkMTJiNjI2MmNmODA0ODBmOTU1YTJhNmEyMDE1MzJlIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiO
jE1Mzk4MjQyOTcsImV4cCI6MTUzOTgyNDM1NywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZ
XNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcGkxIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNsaWVudCIsInNjb3BlIjpbImFwaTEiXX0.SjBbzIgNfhZ7K_BfrP6tRR71_VDRyxbUWdm0_7TEO8Tof
_BnXpxMipjeNylVenzEl8rzC5UlkajQpGmKsmPiBKB16QOgkYJjIMitOrjJ0xG-HzgbfW9umxh-mvYMk8aJj2uFYCX6DEs9XsH0Y9U5R4Qxx3zCwkq8SMtwM
4uN3mEJPu_zu7CUp0R7bAmsyjwxvx_s1BkjdGRdwOJ1JaobYqFx800oI5Q19wpWfCoYRAm9fQVBLAh7oJK07iNg037KSam9sAHiLCMh-JsRSHE3alLSEHNAQ
bMWTVJDD5s5ssjDS6XZFuVkGGL1Ezb8wpJkgdA2z_g6h9zHK9pTt3exmw",
  "expires_in": 60,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

360 seconds into using the access token expires and there is no refresh token to go get another access token.  Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using **Client Credentials** grant type therefore you don't need a **Refresh Token** to request another **Access Token** as your client (application) is trusted.

**Refresh Tokens** are only required with grant types that required user interaction and are used to avoid having to go back to the user to obtain their credentials.

See http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html:

> Refresh tokens are supported for the following flows: authorization
>   code, hybrid and resource owner password credential flow. The clients
>   needs to be explicitly authorized to request refresh tokens by setting
>   AllowOfflineAccess to true.

Comment: Thank you!  Here is my question, when I change the code to have the user name and password I still don't get a refresh token:

Comment: var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret");
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice", "password", "api1");

Comment: try adding the `offline_access` scope like: `var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret"); var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice", "password", "api1 offline_access");`